# Excel formula translation to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, loops

I'm stuck translating the following excel formula to Python 3 code:

```
=IF(B1="";A1&D1;A1&VLOOKUP(B1;table_2!table_2_col_A:table_2_col_B;2;FALSE))
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't produce the same results that are in the original excel file column:

```
excel_df['new_col)'] = ''

for i, j, k in zip(excel_df['B'], 
                   excel_df['A'], 
                   excel_df['D']):

    for v, x in zip(table_2['A'], 
                    table_2['B']):

        if not pd.isnull(i):

            if i in v:

                excel_df.at[i, 'new_col'] = j + x

        elif pd.isnull(i):

            excel_df.at[i, 'new_col'] = j + k
```

I'm sorry because i can't generate example data for you to try, and i can't share the original data here. I would be very grateful if you could provide any indications or corrections to better adapt this excel formula to python.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: This will probably not receive a useful answer unless you provide some example data, with an expected output. The example data does not have to be your actual data, but can be made up to represent your problem.

Comment: use `np.where` -- `np.where(conditional,true-value,false-value)` if you're doing a vlookup then you juse need to do a merge. but as Erfan has said, just povide a few rows each of both your tables.

Comment: Hi @Datanovice could you provide an example eskeleton code using the schema you propose please?

Comment: happy to as long as you provide some data that mimics your problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry but i just can't. I'm working with huge excel files which have a high number of different cases, i would need a lot of time to go through all data and provide a minimum reproducible example. Your answer doesn't need to be 100% correct, i will be happy if it just point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
tbl2 = table_2[['col_A','col_B']]

## df has columns A,B,D
df = df.merge(tbl2,left_on=['B'],right_on=['col_A'],how='left')
# df['col_B'] = df['col_B'].fillna(0)
df['result'] = np.where(df['B']=='',df['A']*df['D'],df['A']*df['col_B'])
```

Comment: Thank you!! useful enough!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table look something like this:

```
>>> df 

    A    B   C   D
0  A0   B0  C0  D0
1  A1   B1  C1  D1
2  A2   B2  C2  D2
3  A3  NaN  C3  D3
4  A4   B4  C4  D4
5  A5   B5  C5  D5
6  A6  NaN  C6  D6
7  A7  NaN  C7  D7
8  A8  NaN  C8  D8
9  A9  NaN  C9  D9

>>> table_2

      A    B
0   B20  x20
1   B19  x19
2   B18  x18
3   B17  x17
4   B16  x16
5   B15  x15
6   B14  x14
7   B13  x13
8   B12  x12
9   B11  x11
10  B10  x10
11   B9   x9
12   B8   x8
13   B7   x7
14   B6   x6
15   B5   x5
16   B4   x4
17   B3   x3
18   B2   x2
19   B1   x1
```

Here's one way to do it:

```
# Prepare table_2 into a "look up" table of sort
>>> table_2 = table_2.set_index('A')

# Formula translation
>>> df = df.assign(result=df.apply(lambda x: (x['A'] + x['D']) if pd.isna(x['B']) else table_2['B'].get(x['B']), axis=1))
```

Result:

```
>>> df
    A    B   C   D result
0  A0   B0  C0  D0   None
1  A1   B1  C1  D1     x1
2  A2   B2  C2  D2     x2
3  A3  NaN  C3  D3   A3D3
4  A4   B4  C4  D4     x4
5  A5   B5  C5  D5     x5
6  A6  NaN  C6  D6   A6D6
7  A7  NaN  C7  D7   A7D7
8  A8  NaN  C8  D8   A8D8
9  A9  NaN  C9  D9   A9D9
```

Using `apply` is not exactly the ideal solution, but it gives you some flexibility of handling the conditions.